# Java out of heap space error while calling constructor.newInstance(String) multiple times

Tags: java

```
String type = “ClassNames”;
MyInterface mi = (MyInterface) constructor.newInstance(type);
```

Above code snippet is called multiple times (around 3000 Classes) in my program and this leads to out of heap space error.
Heap size reaches to 1024mb.
Any workaround to keep the heap size low?
Thanks!

**The interface**

```
public interface MyInterface { 
    public String[] getRowHeader(); 
    public String[] getHeaderTable();    
    public String[][] getDataForSearch();
    public String getInfoText();
}
```

**Public Class implementation**

```
public TablePanel() {
    try {
        guiInit();
    } 
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This guiInit() does the swing component initialization.

In the same class methods are implemented like this below

```
public String[][] getDataForSearch()  
{
    return rowNames;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. I'd say in general 3,000 plain class instances should not be a problem... it really depends on the constructor, it might just allocate a bunch of other objects. So how does the constructor of the MyInterface (or the implementation you use) look like?

Comment: `public interface MyInterface {`
        `public String[] getRowHeader();`
        `public String[] getHeaderTable(); 
        public String[][] getDataForSearch();
        public String getInfoText();
    }`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get how to paste the code in this comment section :(

Comment: NP, updated it for you. But the interface does not really help. How does the implementation (`public class`) look like, especially the constructor?

Comment: thanks! I have updated the question, one xml file have all the class names and for each class this gui will be generated separately, this is a legacy code so couldn't do much to change the implementation.

Comment: I think you don't get what people are asking for.  The problem is that you created thousands of `ClassNames` instance and then you run out of heap.  So you should show what's inside the class `ClassNames` and how it is constructed, which is meaningful for the memory usage.  Those guiInit() or getter is not giving any useful hints to other.

Comment: btw, I suggest you find a profiler and check what is the stuffs using up your memory.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this ClassName is variable, it will be parsed from an XML file where all the classes are listed, so there are 3000 different classes. each class instance is created.

Comment: There r around 3000 tables with difrnt options to assign data (checkbox, textbox radio buttons etc), when saved this data goes to few data files. This each table is a separate class. This same tool can open those data file and re-generate the GUI again. My requirement is to export all the tables’ data (GUI) to html file. I am parsing each and every file and writing in an html file. So i have used the 'constructor.newInstance' to create the instances of each class and creating instances of these many classes exhausting the heap space. This is a large source code so redesigning is not possible

Comment: If there are that many of different kinds of object created, I will strongly suggest you get a profiler.  Have a look what is occupying most of your memory.  They will be your first target of code cleanup.  Refactoring and redesign often happens, even for huge projects.  However you should know what is causing the problem before you do your redesign.  If you insist no redesign can be done, then I believe no one can help you, as the problem is most probably caused by design limitation.

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks for your input. I have analyzed the code and found that while exporting all the GUI related objects are also recreated separately for each class and taking up huge space in heap. At least I have to redesign the export logic.

Answer (score 1):

No one is able to help you without knowing what you are doing in your code.  The solution is closely depends on what you are doing.

Are there any memory leak? like, you are still holding reference to the object instance that is no longer needed, which prevent GC from freeing up the memory?

If you really need that many instances, you may consider doing some redesign on your classes to make it takes less memory, for example, using Fly-weight pattern, or try to reuse already-created instances, or make use of more space-efficient data structure etc.

Also, consider redesign your logic, to avoid the need of allocating that many object.  For example, if your application is processing an input file, avoid doing "read the whole file and transform it all to POJO, then do the logic".  See if you can "read the file partially and create corresponding POJO, do the logic for that part, then go for next part".

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your time, I have checked for all the memory leak.